# Cant connect to postgres db from pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

stackoverflow community!

i cant connect to postgres db from pgadmin

both of them run on separate containers

**PGADMIN**:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: email@email.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 123
    volumes:
      - C:\Docker\pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  pgadmin:
```

**POSTGRES**:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - C:\Docker\postgres14:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Pgadmin opens succcessfully from browser by address http://localhost:8080/browser/#

But in pgadmin i create server and type next data:

```
CREATE -> SERVER::

Name : mydatabase

**Connection**
hostname address : host.docker.internal
Port: 5432
maintance db : postgres
username: admin
password: admin
```

What i am doing here wrong ?

Comment: What OS is your host?

Comment: Hello. My OS is Windows 10

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: unable to connect to server

Answer (score 0):

Because postgres is not in the pgadmin network, you can modify compose as

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: email@email.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 123
    volumes:
      - C:\Docker\pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    restart: unless-stopped
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - C:\Docker\postgres14:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  pgadmin:
  postgres:
```

or you can find the network driver local ip:

```
docker network ls
```

shows network drivers, so find your driver then by:

```
docker network inspect network_name
```

find the local ip of driver.